# Steering mechanism for City-scale vehicle

Tags: power-functions, vehicle, design, city, steering

I'd like to build city-scale (6 studs wide) motorized vehicles with PF remote control. There are already several suggestions on [how to motorize wheels](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/184/how-can-i-motorize-city-scale-wheels). The next challenge is steering 
 mechanism that can be connected to motor (with gears or by other means). Sure, solution with 2 rotation axes is preferred, but rigid axle turning at center is OK too.

Comment: That sounds incredibly ambitious. Do you have a model you would like to modify or are you building from scratch?

Comment: @Ambo100 actually I've seen a working model carrying 2 M-motors, train battery box and IR receiver.

Comment: I tried out rack and pinion steering but it didn't work to well for such small scale. It would be around 12 studs including the motor, and another 8 for the back end motor. Wouldn't work unless you had a bus.

Answer (score 11):

It's difficult, but not impossible. A rigid axle turning at the centre would be mechanically simpler. As my crude drawing illustrates;
I would place a 24-tooth gear over the [2x4 wheel axle](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=30157). A 8-tooth gear is optional but will provide finer control over the steering. The two teeth gears can also be replaced with a pulley gear.

[image]

This technique however will not work with current Lego CITY vehicals unless the wheel arch is removed or replaced.

[image: Wheel arch]

Comment: So the wheel axel where the gears are connected would not be connected to the frame of the vehicle? In other words, the wheels would be connected to the axel, which is connected to the gears? I'm not sure I understand how the movement would work...