# How can I create a simple steering mechanism for a car?

Tags: building, vehicle, steering

Just curious about this. How can I create a simple steering mechanism for a car? Either motorized or non-motorized solutions are fine; just not overly complex.

Comment: Related: http://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/537/132

Comment: How big will your car be?

Comment: @Ambo100 The first question is somewhat relevant, but I'm not asking for a motorized solution. To answer your second question, I don't know. This is more of a general question.

Comment: My solution doesn't have to be motorised, you can use a gear or pulley wheel to manually adjust the wheel angle.

Comment: I'm confused: the OP explicitly states in comments that he's not looking for a motorised solution, but an approved edit includes motorisation as a requirement?

Comment: Sorry, I took pcantin's comment below over the OP's comment above.

Comment: Wow sorry. I haven't been keeping up with this question. I'm going to edit my question to include both motorized and non-motorized solutions…

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The most common I've seen is rack and pinion:

[image]

Essentially you have two parallel beams with one fixed to the car's chassis. The other bar moves horizontally which changes the direction of the wheels. Attach some gears and you can hook it up to a steering wheel.

The steering technique has been used in the [Whirl N' Wheel Super Truck](http://peeron.com/scans/5590-1/11/) (5590)
 set. The instructions for the set show how an similar rack and pinion mechanism.